# Bluetooth device names not showing up

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying for the first time (on this installation) to set up a Bluetooth mouse with my computer running a stripped down Ubuntu Bionic.

I believe my device is detected properly. The problem is that I can't figure out which one it is because the Bluetooth module(?) only displays device IDs in hex and no human readable names at all, neither in the blueman applet nor in the `bluetoothctl`. `bluetoothctl` says:

```
Device 40:06:37:CF:D8:50 40-06-37-CF-D8-50                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Device 7F:2F:05:73:BF:09 7F-2F-05-73-BF-09
Device 4B:91:14:95:7C:A9 4B-91-14-95-7C-A9
Device 08:F8:C2:7D:59:69 08-F8-C2-7D-59-69
Device A4:31:35:07:0B:4E A4-31-35-07-0B-4E
Device DC:56:E7:50:93:4E DC-56-E7-50-93-4E
Device 68:C6:01:FA:79:E3 68-C6-01-FA-79-E3
Device 44:3D:DC:E9:3A:01 44-3D-DC-E9-3A-01
Device 28:1C:A5:8B:81:C9 28-1C-A5-8B-81-C9
Device 5D:C7:2C:D4:7A:39 5D-C7-2C-D4-7A-39
Device 40:CB:C0:EB:5C:64 40-CB-C0-EB-5C-64
```

and eg.

```
[bluetooth]# info 7F:2F:05:73:BF:09
Device 7F:2F:05:73:BF:09 (random)
        Alias: 7F-2F-05-73-BF-09
        Paired: no
        Trusted: no
        Blocked: no
        Connected: no
        LegacyPairing: no
        ManufacturerData Key: 0x004c
        ManufacturerData Value:
  10 05 03 1c 5f 51 09                             ...._Q.
```

Could anyone help me get the actual device names to be displayed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you figure it out? What WiFi device do you have? `lspci`? What motherboard?

Comment: Thanks for the response but it was a while ago. I'm no longer on the same hardware or even distribution and I'm no longer experiencing these issues

Comment: Don't remember any rough details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem on Debian/Ubuntu env + a USB BT dongle (specifically [this BT dongle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07J5WFPXX)).

Originally, we had the same thought that the device names were just not displaying properly. But it seemed it was a dongle driver/firmware issue, that **it actually could not detect the BT devices properly**. The actual devices we wanted to pair wasn't even on the list, so it wasn't a problem of "how to show the actual device names". Changing the dongle eventually properly listed the correct devices with their correct names.

For details, the faulty dongle was from Broadcom Corp.

`dmesg:`

```
  idVendor           0x0a5c Broadcom Corp.
  idProduct          0x21e8 BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
  bcdDevice            1.12
  iManufacturer           1 Broadcom Corp
  iProduct                2 BCM20702A0
```

The working dongle was from CSR.

`lsusb:`

```
  idVendor           0x0a12 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd
  idProduct          0x0001 Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
  bcdDevice           88.91
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                2 CSR8510 A10
```

It's quite known that Broadcom Corp has some compatibility issues with Linux. Plugging in the dongle will even show this firmware error:

```
[  640.092061] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci-hcd
[  640.246636] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0a5c, idProduct=21e8
[  640.253361] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  640.260521] usb 1-1: Product: BCM20702A0
[  640.264445] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
[  640.269059] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 001986001693
[  640.395410] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[  640.401416] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[  640.422427] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
[  640.427410] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[  640.433521] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd failed with error -2
[  640.442946] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd not found
```

It seems they don't provide *official* drivers for Linux, only for Windows. You could try downloading and installing *unofficial* Broadcom Corp firmware files from here:

https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware

> This package intentended to provide firmware of Broadcom WIDCOMM® Bluetooth devices (including BCM20702, BCM20703, BCM43142 chipsets and other) for Linux kernel. Since February 2017, Broadcom ships their drivers directly to Windows Update service. They can be downloaded here.

Check the [FW-to-DEVICE mapping](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/DEVICES.md) for your machine. This thread over at AskUbuntu might also be worth a read: [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working/632348#632348).

Basically, it might be a Broadcom Corp firmware issue. It's not just that the device names are not displayed, but the devices you want to pair might not even be on that list. Check with a different BT adapter.

Comment: Thanks! As it stands it's not currently an issue for me but I will look into this if I ever experience the same problem again.